# Codeigniter Datamapper automated created updated fields

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-datamapper

Seems like this should be the easy part, but I can't seem to get this going. My `created` and `updated` fields are not being populated. I've tried renaming the fields to something different, but no go. Other than the schema and setting up the class (very basic) as below, am I missing something?

Codeigniter v2.1.2
Datamapper ORM v1.8.2.1

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

User Class:

```
<?php

class User extends DataMapper
{

    function User()
    {
        parent::DataMapper();
    }

}
```

Comment: Well, something interesting. I allowed NULL for the `created` and `updated` columns. When I create a new user `created` is set to '0000-00-00 00:00:00' and `updated` is NULL. So it seems that it set the `created` column, but do I need edit a time config somewhere?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, found the answer and hopefully this will help someone out. I needed to set the following in the application/config/datamapper.php file:

```
$config['local_time'] = TRUE;
$config['unix_timestamp'] = FALSE;
$config['timestamp_format'] = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';
```

Comment: By default Datamapper is configured to use integers for your timestamps, and store a UNIX timestamp, which is a lot more efficient than a MYSQL datetime field.

Comment: but the user docs say 'Note: By default, the Created and Updated fields are of the DateTime type, and GMT/UTC time is used.' (http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/pages/timestamp.html accessed 2013/04/23)

Comment: @WanWizard : Fields updated and created have to be allow nil. Am I right? And this library place nil at updated field on the creation of model. Not that updated field become same as creation on creation of the model at database. Is this the intended behavior for the library?

Answer (score 0):

In your config/datamapper.php file ensure 'created_field' and 'updated_field' are set to match your DB columns. Or you can override them in the model itself. ie.

```
<?php

class User extends DataMapper
{
    var $created_field = 'created';
    var $updated_field = 'updated';

    function User()
    {
        parent::DataMapper();
    }

}
```